# host naming for hbase cluster in /etc/hosts

Tags: hbase

> Updated file: `/etc/hosts` file looks like this

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   saichanda-OptiPlex-9020

10.0.3.18       master 
10.0.3.68       slave1
10.0.3.70       slave2
```

where, my system IP is `10.0.3.18` and admin name: `saichanda`, I am the master node 
then I have two more systems with hbase installed, and their IP's are `10.0.3.68`and `10.0.3.70`, and the usernames of the two slave systems are `dmacs` and `dmacs`. A similar `/etc/hosts` file in slaves also with localhost name change.

when I start my hbase in the master node, I get the following error..
`sudo ./bin/start-hbase.sh starting master, logging to /usr/local/hbase/bin/../logs/hbase-root-master-saichanda-OptiPlex-9020.out`
`master: ssh: Could not resolve hostname master: Name or service not known`
`slave1: ssh: Could not resolve hostname slave1: Name or service not known`
`slave2: ssh: Could not resolve hostname slave2: Name or service not known`

> My regionservers file looks like this,( in master node)

`master`

`slave1`
`slave2`

I could resolve ssh error in some way using `ssh-add` but when I run the hbase, I get the following error:

```
saichanda@saichanda-OptiPlex-9020:~$ /usr/local/hbase/bin/start-hbase.sh     starting master, logging to /usr/local/hbase/logs/hbase-saichanda-master-saichanda-OptiPlex-9020.out
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/local/hbase/logs/SecurityAuth.audit (Permission denied)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:133)
at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.setFile(RollingFileAppender.java:207)
at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
The authenticity of host 'slave2 (10.0.3.68)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:UBvk5FkG3KfSMREsDIKbob1l782fozXQHT6+3J6F2Y4.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? slave1: @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
slave1: @       WARNING: POSSIBLE DNS SPOOFING DETECTED!          @
slave1: @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
slave1: The ECDSA host key for slave1 has changed,
slave1: and the key for the corresponding IP address 10.0.3.70
slave1: is unchanged. This could either mean that
slave1: DNS SPOOFING is happening or the IP address for the host
slave1: and its host key have changed at the same time.
slave1: Offending key for IP in /home/saichanda/.ssh/known_hosts:18
slave1:   remove with:
slave1:   ssh-keygen -f "/home/saichanda/.ssh/known_hosts" -R 10.0.3.70
slave1: @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
slave1: @    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
slave1: @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
slave1: IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
slave1: Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
slave1: It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
slave1: The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
slave1: SHA256:D9udCvOaKAFGwNbuIpBa+pQErZSDTjLg4m4LJ+s8DzM.
slave1: Please contact your system administrator.
slave1: Add correct host key in /home/saichanda/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
slave1: Offending ECDSA key in /home/saichanda/.ssh/known_hosts:22
slave1:   remove with:
slave1:   ssh-keygen -f "/home/saichanda/.ssh/known_hosts" -R slave1
slave1: ECDSA host key for slave1 has changed and you have requested     strict checking.
slave1: Host key verification failed.
master: starting regionserver, logging to /usr/local/hbase/bin/../logs/hbase-saichanda-regionserver-saichanda-OptiPlex-9020.out
master: log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
master: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/local/hbase/bin/..    /logs/SecurityAuth.audit (Permission denied)
master:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
master:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
master:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
master:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:133)
master:     at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
master:     at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.setFile(RollingFileAppender.java:207)
master:     at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
master:     at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)

slave2: Host key verification failed.
```

Comment: what does your /usr/local/hbase/conf/regionservers file look like?

Comment: Also, in /etc/hosts you should enter the host names of slave machines, not user names. So how can you have two of the same entries pointing at two separate IPs?

Comment: I have updated my /etc/hosts file in the question above, and also updated the regionservers file of master node. Now I don't get type the password for the same, I get in the terminal the following when start the hbase...........` sudo ./bin/start-hbase.sh `
starting master, logging to `/usr/local/hbase/bin/../logs/hbase-root-master-saichanda-OptiPlex-9020.out`
`root@master's password: root@slave2's password: root@slave1's password:` It doesn't allow me to give password

Comment: what should be there in the regionservers files of slave nodes, depending on what is there in the regionserver file of master node. My hbase-site.xml file looks like this:
 <property>
        <name>hbase.master</name>
        <value>master:60000</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
        <value>hdfs://master:50000/hbase</value>
</property>

along with other content... Is this right?

Comment: sorry if the documented question is not clear, if that is the case, I shall reframe whole of my problem again with specifications to all of the file contents.

Comment: You use the regionservers file to specify all region servers (as host names) and then you need /etc/hosts to specify IP addresses for each of those host names. it seems at this stage this is all correct (your initial problem was that your /etc/hosts was stating user names rather than host names). I would guess that if you removed all passwords, everything would probably work. So now you just need to figure out how to do permissioned access. I don't know how to do that, but I'm sure you can search that around.

Comment: Did you follow the steps mentioned in https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#quickstart_fully_distributed to enable SSH password less login for each machine?

Comment: @SubashKunjupillai, I followed that, now, I'm almost done.. region server started.. but now, the problem comes only at master node, signing in: It says,,agent refused operation .. signing in failed.. and request for password comes for the master node.

Comment: Can you please get logs of master and slave and share us?

Comment: The file is too huge to fit here.. how do I share I that.. here>> is there any other way to share it?

Comment: Put your logs in pastebin or dropbox and share us the link.

Comment: @SubashKunjupillai,  the updated problem is noted in this [https://pastebin.com/E8MN6Qtt] as you have suggested.. I get host key verification failed even after trying the suggestions like `ssh-keygen -R hostname` many times, something is going wrong at basic level which I'm not able to observe, Can you conclude this problem for me by solving it with link provided.

Comment: pastbin link is not working, please share the updated link

Comment: This is the link for the post: https://pastebin.com/E8MN6Qtt

I don't know why it isn't working for you